# TOP Rock Paper Scissors Project

Tags: javascript

This is my first time posting a question so I apologize if I posted incorrectly. I am doing The Odin Project and I am stuck on why my code returns undefined and does not run my return code on the function singleRound. I also do not understand why my game function console.logs all of the code and does not run based on if the computer or the player got the point. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

```
function computerPlay(computerSelection){
  let choices=['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
 let pick= choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];
}

//plays single round

  function singleRound(playerSelection,computerSelection){


    
    if (playerSelection === 'Paper'|| computerSelection === 'Rock') {
      playerPoints=+1
        return "You Win! Paper beats Rock";
    }
      
    else if (playerSelection === 'Paper'|| computerSelection=='Scissors') {
     computerPoints=+1
      return"Paper does not beat Scissors! You lose";
       
            }
      
      else if (playerSelection === 'Paper' || computerSelection ==='Paper') {
      return "Paper does not beat Paper! Tie Game!";
         
    }
    
      else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' || computerSelection ==='Paper') {
  computerPoints=+1
      return"Rock does not beat Paper! You lose";
         
    }
    
          else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' || computerSelection ==='Rock') {
      return"Rock does not beat Rock! Tie Game!";
            
    }
      else if (playerSelection === 'Rock' || computerSelection ==='Scissors') {
       playerPoints=+1
      return "Rock beats Scissors! You Win!";
    }
    
      else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' || computerSelection ==='Paper') {
        playerPoints=+1
      return "Scissors Beats Paper! You Win!";
      }
    
      else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' || computerSelection ==='Rock') {
       computerPoints=+1
      return "Scissors does not beat Rock! You lose!";
      
      }
      
      else if (playerSelection === 'Scissors' || computerSelection ==='Scissors') {
      return"Scissors does not beat Scissors! Tie Game!";


      }
  } 

  //plays 5 rounds**strong text**
  function game(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   let playerPoints=0;
    let computerPoints=0;
    if (playerPoints === i++)
    {console.log('1 point for player');}
    else if (computerPoints === i++){
      console.log('1 point for the computer');}
    else if (computerPoints !== i++ && playerPoints !== i++){ console.log('No one won this round. No points for either of you.');}
    if (playerPoints= 5 && computerPoints< 5){
      console.log('Yay! Congrats! You won the game! ');
    }
    if (computerPoints=5 && playerPoints < 5){
      console.log('Sorry :/ You lost the game.');
    }
    else{
        endGame();
    }
}
  }

let playerSelection=['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
const computerSelection=computerPlay
console.log('The computer chose:' + computerSelection());
prompt("Do you want to pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
console.log(singleRound(playerSelection,computerSelection));
computerPlay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return pick; in the computerPlay function. It is returning undefined because computerPlay returns nothing in the above code

```
function computerPlay(computerSelection){
  let choices=['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
  let pick= choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];
  return pick
}
```

Also I would change the bottom code to the following since computerPlay returns the selection and we want to preserve the selection between the first console.log statement and when you call the singleRound

```
let playerSelection=['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
const computerSelection=computerPlay()
console.log('The computer chose:' + computerSelection);
prompt("Do you want to pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
console.log(singleRound(playerSelection,computerSelection));
computerPlay();
```